# ggplot labels on top of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

To illustrate my problem, I have provided the plot below:

[image]

My question is thus: Is there are way to bring the labels (made with geom_labels) on top of the lines? I have tried hjust and vjust, but no combination of those two solves it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You need to rearrange the layers, `ggplot() + geom_line() + .. + geom_labels()`

Comment: `ggplot` will always put the last added layer on top.

Comment: You have to create a set of vector for `hjust` and `vjust` to give placement for each of the point seperately and use that vector.

Comment: @beetroot Thank you so much, it worked like a charm!

Comment: @Axeman Thanks, I am not that new to ggplot, however I didn't know it did that. Again, thanks!

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you for the link, I will give it a read! :)